# Let $p$ be an odd prime and G be a group of order $4p^3$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, sylow-theory

Let $p$ be an odd prime and G be a group of order $4p^3$. Prove that G either has a normal subgroup of order $p^2$ or $p^3$.

By Sylow's Theorem, $n_p \equiv 1\pmod{p}$ and $n_p |$ $\mid G \mid$, so $n_p \in \{1,4\}$. If $n_p = 1$ were done so suppose $n_p = 4$. Hence $4\equiv 1\pmod{p}$ which implies $3=0$ mod $p$ and so $p=3$. Thus we have that $|G| = 4 \cdot 3^3$.

I'm not sure where to go from here.

Comment: Try to check that the intersection of the four Sylow $3$-subgroups cannot have order $1$ or $p$.

Comment: The kernel  of the conjugation action of $G$ on the set of four Sylow $3$-subgroups has order $p^2$.

Comment: @DerekHolt I don't see this... If $\phi : G \to S_{p^3}$ is the homomorphism afforded by that action then we just know $\mid G/$Ker$\phi \mid$ |  $p^3!$ right?

Comment: There are four Sylow subgroups so the map is $G \to S_4$, not $G \to S_{p^3}$.

Comment: @DerekHolt Oh right, but we still only know $p^2$| $\mid$ Ker$\phi$ $\mid$. I don't think it's immediate that they are equal but I'm working on that now

Comment: By Sylow's theorem the image of $\phi$ is transitive, and hence has order divisible by $4$.

Comment: @DerekHolt Sorry but I'm not familiar with this fact. What set is $\phi(G)$ transitive on? Could you expand on this?

Comment: One part of Sylow's theorem says that all Sylow subgroups are conjugate, which is equivalent to the image of $\phi$ being a transitive subgroup of $S_4$.